# Visual Studio for Mac: How to fix the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime. The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, blazor

I initially created a .net app on Mac and did some work on it and stopped updating it but recently I wanted to get back to adding some new features but Im getting the error

**"The operation failed due to an internal error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=stuff'. The system cannot find the file specified."**

PS this also occurs when I make a new app so it may be an issue with how I have my dev environment setup but can't seem to pin point how fix it.

For some reason it looks like visual studio cannot find any target frameworks.

[image: visual studio cannot find any target frameworks]

[image: dotnet --info]
Any help to fix the issue would be appreciated

Steps that I have already tried:

1. Rebooted my machine.
2. Reinstalled visual studio
3. Reinstalled dotnet

Comment: Use another development tool please, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/what-happened-to-vs-for-mac?view=vsmac-2022